# How to check no of substrings?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

How to check the number of substrings in string `s` that contains both string `a` and `b`? For example if input is :`ab c cabc` . Answer should come as 3 as `cabc` has 3 substrings that include both `ab` and `c` : `cab`, `cabc`, `abc`.

Comment: Have a look at this similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593637/find-the-number-of-substrings-in-a-string-containing-equal-numbers-of-a-b-c/47605445

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'ab'
b = 'c'
c = 'cabc'

total = 0
substring = []
substring.append(c)

for counter in range (0,len(c)):
    substring.append(c[counter:len(c)])

for i in substring:
    if a in i and b in i:
        total += 1
print(total)
```

Pretty much you can find every single substring then check all of them. Ineffective, but It worked for your test case and some extra I checked. Hope this helps!

Comment: First, checking every substring is horribly inefficient. Second, you're not even checking every substring. You put `c` in the list twice, and you're leaving out substrings that don't go to the end of `c`.